# Button of two different forms on the same line

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp

I just signed up and I really hope you can help me. I'm trying to put two buttons from two different forms on the same line; I helped myself by looking at this site and other sites. The "Delete" button works while the "Update" button does not. Can you kindly help me?
I am creating a CRUD in Spring.

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>

<head>
<spring:url value="/resources/css/style1.css" var="style1" />
<link href="${style1}" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head>
<body>

    <form id="update" action="/update" method="post">
      <c:forEach var="fruit" items="${listFruit}">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${fruit.id}" /> 

Name:                  <input type="text" name="name" value="${fruit.name}" />
        
Geographical Origin:   <input type="text" name="geographicalorigin" value="${fruit.geographicalorigin}" />

      </c:forEach>
    </form>

    <form id="delete" action="/delete" method="POST">
      <c:forEach var="fruit" items="${listFruit}">
        <input name="fruit" type="hidden" value="${fruit.id}" />
      </c:forEach>
    </form>

    <input type="submit" id="up" value="Update" />
    <input type="submit" id="de" value="Delete" />


    <script>
      document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('update').submit();
      });

      document.getElementById('de').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('delete').submit();
      });
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```js
@RequestMapping(value = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView update1(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("geographicalorigin") String geographicalorigin, ModelAndView mv, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) throws ParseException {

        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
        fruit.setId(id);
        fruit.setName(name);
        fruit.setGeographicalorigin(geographicalorigin);    
        
        int counter = fruitDao.updateFruit(fruit);

        if (counter > 0) {
            mv.addObject("msg", "successful update");
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/update/"+id);
        } else {
            mv.addObject("msg", "Error");
        }

        mv.setViewName("updatefruit");

        return mv;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView deleteFruit(ModelAndView mv, @RequestParam("fruit") String id)
            throws IOException {

        int counter = fruitDao.deleteFruit(fruit);

        if (counter > 0) {
            mv.addObject("msg", "Delete");
        } else {
            mv.addObject("msg", "Error.");
        }

        mv.setViewName("deletefruit");

        return mv;
    }
```

Before putting the two buttons on the same line, the code was this. Here they both work perfectly.

```js
<form action="/update" method="post">
  <c:forEach var="fruit" items="${listFruit}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${fruit.id}" /> 

VARIOUS INPUT TIPE "TEXT"
  
      <input type="submit" id="up" value="Update" /> 
  </c:forEach>
</form>

<form action="/delete" method="POST">
  <c:forEach var="fruit" items="${listFruit}">
    <input name="fruit" type="hidden" value="${fruit.id}" />
    <input type="submit" id="de" value="Delete" />
  </c:forEach>
</form>
```

**ERROR:**
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNAwV.png)

Error Console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null at HTMLInputElement.  (923:57)

where 923 is the id entered by me in the form

**VIEW SOURCE:**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>



<html>

<head>

<link href="/FruitSpring/resources/css/style1.css;jsessionid=1D2A5AE3E88AEE99FC67D7C8644D0666" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head>
<body>
 
<form id="update "action="/update" method="post">
<pre>

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="874" />
                                
Name:           <input type="text" name="name" value="Orange" />
        
Geographical Origin:             <input type="text" name="geographicalorigin" value="" />
    
    
</pre>
</form>
    
<form id="delete" action="/delete" method="POST">

      <input name="fruit" type="hidden" value="874"/>
      
</form>
      <input type="submit" id="up" value="Update" />
      <input type="submit" id="de" value="Delete"/>



<script>
  document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('click', function() {
     document.getElementById('update').submit();
   });

  document.getElementById('de').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('delete').submit();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They are on the same line actually

Comment: yes they are exactly on the same line, however when I click on the "Update" button the update is not performed.
While, if I click on the "Delete" button, the deletion is successful

Comment: What does the controller code look like?

Comment: Before putting the two buttons on the same line, the "Update" button worked perfectly. I believe the error is in html.
Anyway I put it under the controller.

Comment: Your buttons are outside your forms. Neither of them should be working

Comment: @haldo i put the controller in the post

Comment: @ADyson it is managed with javascript

Comment: Ok so what exactly does "not working" mean? is the form submitted? Does the expected data get sent to the server? Does the PHP controller code read the data? Is there a PHP error? Is there a database error? In short...what debugging have you done to narrow down the problem? If the best you can say is "not working", then I suspect the answer is none. We can't run your code. You need to debug it and get some useful information like error messages, data issues etc. Then if you still can't solve it, you can provide that information here and we can try to help you. We can't guess just from code.

Comment: P.S. `Before putting the two buttons on the same line, the "Update" button worked perfectly.`...then show how it was before please. I would be surprised if simply moving the buttons was the real issue though...I would guess maybe you changed something else at the same time. Either way you need to debug so you can get some idea of where the problem is starting.

Comment: @ADyson It doesn't give me any errors. When I click the "Update" button it just doesn't do anything.
I understand the debug I cannot run it because it is a jsp page.
However, the code as it was before I put it in the post

Comment: Why can't you debug JSP? You can add logging at least even if you don't have a Java debugger available. Anyway so you mean it doesn't even submit the form? Did you check for JavaScript errors, or check the network tool in the browser to see if anything is submitted? You can always debug that with the browser tools

Comment: Because debugging on jsp I can only do it on some instructions; for example now I wanted to debug the instruction related to the "Update" form action and I can't do it because it doesn't let me put the breakpoint on that instruction.
As I am a beginner, can you kindly explain to me how I can debug with the browser tools?

Comment: You should be able to put breakpoints within the Update method so that you can see what happens when you arrive there. Anyway to debug the client-side code using browser tools, open your browser's Developer Tools (press F12 in most browsers). Then (in Chrome at least) you have the Console (showing Javascript errors and warnings), Sources (which lets you debug the javascript line by line), Network which shows you form submissions, AJAX calls etc and Elements which shows you the HTML and CSS. Those are the main ones you'll find yourself using. Other browsers' tools are similar as well.

Comment: I tried to run the code using the browser tools. When I click on the "Update" button, the following error appears: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null at HTMLInputElement

Comment: Ok so that means you tried to run the `.submit()` function on an object that was actually `null`. Obviously that can't work. But in turn it means that `document.getElementById('update')` must have returned `null`. Which is strange because you have `form id="update"`. The code you've shown us here wouldn't produce that error (I tested it myself quickly). So maybe the code you've got above is not an accurate reflection of the code in your real application?

Comment: But anyway you don't need JavaScript to solve this at all. See my answer below.

Comment: The code is exactly that, I haven't changed anything. I do one thing: I now edit my original post by putting the code in full (to prove that's exactly that).
I also answer here for the other answer: yes exactly, that javascript code is used to manage the buttons. But if I remove the javascript code and add the "form = ..." attribute, the "Delete" button doesn't work either; I just tried this. So I'm forced to put it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit buttons which are outside a form don't submit anything. I assume you added your JavaScript to try and solve that problem. It *should* work, based on what you've shown in the question, but according to your comments you seem to have a problem with it.

We could try to solve that, but actually you don't need JavaScript for this anyway. Since HTML5 came along, you can associate a button with a form, even though the button it outside the `<form>...</form>` tag.

To do this, you simply add a `form=...` attribute to each button, containing the ID of the target form.

You can then remove your JavaScript entirely.

Demo:

```html
<form id="update" action="/update" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${fruit.id}" />
</form>

<form id="delete" action="/delete" method="POST">
    <input name="fruit" type="hidden" value="${fruit.id}" />
</form>

<input type="submit" id="up" form="update" value="Update" />
<input type="submit" id="de" form="delete" value="Delete" />
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefform

Comment: Yes exactly, that javascript code is used to manage the buttons. But if I remove the javascript code and add the "form = ..." attribute, the "Delete" button doesn't work either; I just tried this. So I'm forced to put it on.

Comment: Well you can see the demo I gave above - it works no problem. So I can only see two possible reasons for your problem 1) you're running this code in a very old browser, or 2) the HTML being rendered into your browser doesn't match the code shown in your question. Rather than showing us the HTML mixed with JSP markup, which is what it's like before it's rendered and sent to the browser, please use your browser's View Source feature to show us the HTML which is actually there in your page, when you try to submit the form. That's what the browser and the Javascript is actually interacting with.

Comment: I was able to get this from Sources (I have Chrome as a browser); as you know this is the first time i do this through the browser. Hope it might help.
I modify the original post by putting (at the end of the post) a screenshot of the Javascript once I click on the "Update" button, where I indicate where the error is given. I also put the error that the Console gives me in full.

Comment: That's nice but it isn't what I asked you to provide.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me what I should do? I repeat, this is the first time I have done such a thing. I'm sorry if I can't do exactly what you want. My browser is Chrome

Comment: As I said before, please use your browser's View Source feature to show us the HTML which is actually there in your page. Your latest screenshot only showed the Javascript. Above it there should be some HTML. Note I'm talking about the **View Source** feature. This is different than the "sources" area in the developer tool. It's an older, more basic feature but it's easier for this purpose. In Chrome you can press Ctrl+U after your page is loaded, in order to open it - it will open in a new browser tab.

Comment: OK now it's clear. I put it in the original post.
I also wanted to do this once I hit the Update button, but as I told you already when I click this button nothing happens; in fact I also checked the database but the update is not performed.
But that line with <anonymous> that comes out in the error what does it mean?

Comment: `<form id="update "`...typo. There shouldn't be a space after `update`. That's your issue right there.

Comment: That will be the same reason why my non-JavaScript solution didn't work - because the form ID doesn't match.  I told you that your real code couldn't be the same as what you were showing us, and that's how it's turned out.

Comment: `But that line with <anonymous>`...I don't see any line with anonymous in it. What are you talking about?

Comment: I hadn't noticed, but the problem was right there. Only for a stupid mistake. Now it works correctly.
I corrected it here in the post the moment I entered the code, thinking the error was unconsciously caused by a key pressed unintentionally by inserting it right here. Although this error was already in the original code.
You were all fantastic, I couldn't find better people like you. I am happy that I registered on this site, I thank you that you have proved available; I thank you again infinitely.

Comment: No problem, glad we got there in the end. Hopefully now you know a little bit more about how to debug your progams too.

Comment: It is clearer; gradually I will learn better since I am a beginner. However your help has served a lot and is also much clearer to understand the code.

Comment: No problem. Please remember to mark this answer as "accepted" then, if it helped you. Thanks :-)

Answer (score -1):

Use formaction formname in form

Formaction in button

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="submit" formaction="/action_page2.php">Submit to another page</button>
</form>
```

Formname

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" id="form1">
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
<label for="lname">Last name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</form>

<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Can you kindly tell me how I can do this with my code? I'm a beginner

Comment: Yes sure but not still now because i am outside for 3 days

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested, the same thing always happens. The "Delete" button works fine, while the "Update" button does not; when I click nothing happens.

Comment: I also tried to do this but I didn't get anything. However I tried to run it with the browser; I get the following error when I click on the "Update" button: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null at HTMLInputElement

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="/update" method="post">
  <c:forEach var="fruit" items="${listFruit}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${fruit.id}" /> 

VARIOUS INPUT TIPE "TEXT"
  
      <input type="submit" id="up" value="Update", formaction="/update" /> 
<input type="submit" id="de" value="Update", formaction="/delete" /> 

  </c:forEach>
</form>
```

See i just add formaction attributes in button

Comment: So just add those two formactions? Should doing so work? Should I delete the part relating to the <script> tag?

Comment: Yes its work in script tag you can select by id up and de